# Why did my network work with crossed cable

Tags: networking, ethernet

I recently checked my home network and noticed that one socket I had was accidentaly set up so it made a cross connection (with pins 3-1 and 2-6) being crossed.

I fixed my mistake but my network also worked fine before doing that. My Setup is basically

```
Router → Wall Socket (which was cross wired) → Switch -> PC
```

and before that

```
Router → Wall Socket → PC
```

Both configurations worked fine with the wall socket being wired regular or crossed. Now I'm curious why this wrong wiring did not cause any problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all modern network interfaces (both in devices and network equipment) automatically detect this condition and adapt. Crossover cables are all but obsolete.

This feature is called "Auto MDI-X".

Comment: Thanks alot. I guess this is the same reason why switches don't use uplink ports anymore than? Man I got old :D

Comment: We too got old. :) If not, we would not even understand your question most likely. ;)